# Cyclic dependency preventing war deployment on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, annotations, jersey, circular-dependency

I have a rest service war (will call A) using Jersey that deploys locally as well as on multiple test Tomcat servers, but fails to load on 1 out of 3 ~prod servers. I believe it is a circular dependency while processing annotations. Another war on the server, B, works everywhere. On the server A fails on, A will work if B is removed. That was discovered through random trial and error. The server setups are identical other than it looks like the war files come up in different orders. I have been looking into ways to force the annotations in the jar files to be processed in a specific order to get rid of any pseudo randomness. I was about to post a question about . Not even realizing if that is the correct way to order the jars, I am multiple tangents deep. So I thought I first might get opinions on the direction I am going.

```
18-Apr-2019 07:43:42.886 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/[A].war]
18-Apr-2019 07:43:43.337 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/[A].war]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/[A]] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [oracle.net.aso.d->oracle.net.aso.e->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->
.
.
.
java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object]
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2100)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2044)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1990)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1960)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1913)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1153)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                ... 10 more
```

Comment: We're encountering the same issue. Were you ever able to fix it? Is it more than one version of the Oracle drivers?

Comment: I don't recall the specific files or versions. I had two dependencies with conflicting child dependencies. The built war had two versions of the same library in it and the older version was loaded first  I put the newer version of it in my projects pom. That resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

```
oracle.net.aso.d->oracle.net.aso.e->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object
```

1. Looking at the message, it scans classes in a single jar and enters into a loop over `java.lang.Object`. This is rather odd. (If it is reproducible with the latest version of Tomcat, e.g. an empty web application with that jar file only, please file an issue).
2. It is rather easy to skip a file from annotation scanning. This is documented on the FAQ pages of Apache Tomcat under "How do I make Tomcat startup faster".

Note that you have not mentioned what version of Apache Tomcat (x.y.z) you are using.